# xpdf configure WARNING - Couldn't find Motif / X

Tags: linux-mint, configure

My environment is `mint17 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64`

I try to compile `xpdf` from source code:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libmotif-dev
wget ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-3.04.tar.gz  
tar xvf xpdf-3.04.tar.gz
cd xpdf-3.04
./configure \
    --with-freetype2-library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-freetype2-includes=/usr/include/freetype2 \
    --with-Xm-library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-Xm-includes=/usr/include/Xm
```

Then I got the WARNING messages:

```
configure: WARNING: Couldn't find X
configure: WARNING: Couldn't find Motif
configure: WARNING: -- You will be able to compile pdftops, pdftotext, pdfinfo, pdffonts, pdfdetach, and pdfimages, but not xpdf or pdftoppm
```

I've checked the library and header files' location. I have no idea why the right location with newest version still caused this.

```
library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so
header files: /usr/include/Xm
```

Also, I google it, few people got the same unsolvable warning message in different platforms.

*I must need to compile `xpdf` from source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to install `libxt-dev`. The `--with-Xm-...` arguments to `./configure` aren't necessary (in fact `--with-Xm-includes=/usr/include/Xm` will fail, since Motif header includes all look for files in an `Xm` sub-directory of the given include directory), and `--with-freetype2-library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` can be dropped too (it's the default):

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libmotif-dev libxt-dev
wget ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdf-3.04.tar.gz  
tar xvf xpdf-3.04.tar.gz
cd xpdf-3.04
./configure --with-freetype2-includes=/usr/include/freetype2
make
```

Comment: Thanks! After I compiled several software's source code, I found that xpdf's configure file is quite different from others. Without your answer, I've never noticed the lost library.